# Audio processing libraries for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, audio, audio-processing

Any recommendation on libraries to do audio processing in Ruby. I need to do the following two tasks:

- Find silences, for which I'm happy to just be able to iterate over each sample in the wave.
- Cut and paste pieces of wav files to form a new wav file.
- Convert wav to mp3, which I will probably leave to lame anyway.

I'm looking for the equivalent of NAudio, a C# library.

Comment: If Ironruby is an option, why not use that and link directly into NAudio since you're familiar with it?

Comment: IronRuby is not an option, only plain good old Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

One option is [ruby-audio](http://github.com/fugalh/ruby-audio), which has a wrapper over libsndfile.

Personally, I haven't had much luck with audio manipulation in pure ruby, but I have used Java libraries from jruby to good effect.

- [Beads](http://www.beadsproject.net/)
- [Ruby-Processing and minim](http://dry.ly/ruby-music-visualizer) - although this adds a different layer in from Processing, it's pretty cool.

Good luck!

Comment: Don't use fugal's ruby-audio. It's slow and buggy.

The latest version is done by warhammerkid (myself) and can be found at http://github.com/warhammerkid/ruby-audio. I generated the rdocs and put them up on my server at http://doc.chromedshark.com/ruby-audio/ so glance through them and see if it works for you.

Comment: You could use rdoc.info to automatically generate the docs.

Comment: It would be nice to know which Java libs you've used, for reference.